# Using chromium embedded framework inside qt application

Tags: c++, qt, chromium-embedded

I am investigating the option of using chromium embedded framework in C++ desktop application to implement new HTML views.

The issue is all the GUI are implemented using QT Framework.

so can chromium embedded framework be used with QT ?

I want some of the views to be implemented using QT while others using Chromium Embedded framework.

First I considered the option of using QTWebEngine but license is not free for commercial use however Chromium embedded framework is an open source

Comment: Given that I found two projects by searching for "qt cef", I would say it is definitely possible. Depends on how much integration you want, really.

Comment: What do you mean by _license is not free for commercial use_? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-licensing.html

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at this project,
https://cefview.github.io/QCefView/

QCefView encapsulates CEF and works for all desktop platforms